# listerner for multiselect in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using ExtJS 3.2.1 Version.

Can we provide `listerners` for `multiselect` in ExtJS?

```
items: [{
    fieldLabel: 'Vehicle List',
    xtype: 'multiselect',
    autoScroll: true,
    name: 'vehicleSimNo',
    id: 'multi_vehicles',
    displayField: 'vehno',
    valueField: 'vehno',
    valueField: 'simno',
    store: store,
    listeners: {
        'select': function() {
            alert("Entered!!");
            //Ext.getCmp('man_dispatch_win').getform().findfield('vehicleSimNo1').enable();
        }
    }
}]
```

Here I'm not getting alert. is there any alternative for  `xtype: 'multiselect'`?

Please give me guidance.

Comment: I have tried to execute multiselect in Extjs 4.0.7 or greater with 'change' event. It is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect` is available since 4.0.7. And we don't have select event for multiselect instead we have change event.

For reference:
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.MultiSelect

Comment: dear Select Smile.. thank you for the replay.i got the ans from here...http://ext4all.com/post/how-to-move-data-between-two-multiselects